# CMake: How to pack a target/file into multiple packages in Linux?

Tags: cmake

I'm working on a project which generates quite a few executables, libraries
and configs, they need to be packed into different packages for deployment.
The problem is, the inclusion of those targets/files is not mutual
exclusive. One target/file can belong to multiple packages.

I'm using CMake 2.8.9 and trying CPack. I know it's kind of doable with
install types. But my platform is Ubuntu, so on Archives/Debs are
acceptable and they don't seem to support that.

With components/groups/parent groups it seems only possible to pack one
target/file into one component/group.

Is there any way out of this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I'll answer it myself for convinience of late comers: from CMake mail list, I got the answer: with cmake 2.8.9 or earlier (so far), run CPack multiple times with different component settings. That's a bit adhoc but does the job.

Comment: To make it work, put:
    `SET(CPACK_ARCHIVE_COMPONENT_INSTALL ON)`
    `SET(CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL_IN_ONE_PACKAGE ON)`

in CMakeLists.txt and run:

    `cpack -G ZIP -D CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL="component_a;common"`
    `cpack -G ZIP -D CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL="component_b;common"`

Answer (score 6):

Why not use components? If I got it right, you want to generate more then one deb from your project.

I am achieving that like this:

```
SET(CPACK_DEB_COMPONENT_INSTALL 1)

INSTALL(TARGETS buildA DESTINATION lib/myproj COMPONENT main)
INSTALL(TARGETS buildB DESTINATION include/myproj COMPONENT dev)
```

When I call `make package` I get two deb's with the suffixes `main` and `dev` containing only what I specified with the INSTALL() statements.

Comment: components are mutual exclusive, meaning that you can't pack one item to multiple packages

Comment: Packing same files into multiple packages will lead to conflict between packages during installation. I think components will suit the needs in almost all real life scenarious.

Comment: Package naming isn't flexible: there is no component with an empty name, the component name is appended only at the end of filename.