# How to build subpackages defined in .spec files using CPACK

Tags: cmake, rpm, packaging, rpmbuild, cpack

Following this tutorial on [Spec File Changes For Subpackages](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-subpack-spec-file-changes.html) I was able to create two RPMs with a single build doing the following:

My spec file is something like:

```
Name:      @CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME@
License:   the license
Summary:   the summary
Group:     Applications
Version: @CPACK_PACKAGE_RELEASE_VERSION@.@CPACK_PACKAGE_MINOR_VERSION@.@CPACK_PACKAGE_SERVICE_PACK@
Release:   @CPACK_PACKAGE_BUILD@
%description
the description...

%package utils
Summary: the utils
Group: Applications
%description utils
description for the utils

%files
...

%files utils
different files
```

Typing `rpmbuild  -ba filename.spec` it creates two RPMs (one for the main package and one for the subpackage **utils**). How can I achieve the same using `include(CPACK)`, and then typing `make package`?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the CMake [`CPackRPM` module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPackRPM.html).  It looks like all you need to do is specify your spec file through a variable.  You will still need to set appropriate [`CPack` variables](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPack.html#module:CPack).